# Judge this position

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

An odd chess crime has occurred. The below position, a criminal one, was on the board when it was intercepted.

[image]

Is it a legal or illegal chess position? Give reasonable proof as to why. You are to judge whether it is guilty (illegal) or innocent (legal)!

Hint:

> The last moves could have been, among many possible ways, 1... Bh6-f8+ 2. Ka3-a2 Ba3, meaning it's White's turn to move in the diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Innocent, as shown by this (surely inefficient) construction:
>
>   1. a4 b5 2. Ra3 bxa4 3. Rh3 c5 4. b3 c4 5. Bb2 c3 6. Rh4 cxb2 7. Nc3 b1=B 8. Rh3 d5 9. Rh4 Kd7 10. Rh3 Kc6 11. Rh4 Kc5 12. Rh3 Kb4 13. Rh4+ Ka3 14. Ne4 d4 15. c3 d3 16. Qc2 dxc2 17. d3 c1=B 18. Nd2 Ka2 19. Rh3 Ka1 20. Rh4 Ba3 21. Rh3 Bd6 22. Rh4 e5 23. Rh3 e4 24. Rh4 e3 25. Rh3 exd2+ 26. Kd1 Ba2 27. Kc2 d1=B+ 28. Kc1 f5 29. e3 f4 30. Be2 f3 31. Rh6 fxe2 32. h3 g5 33. Rh2 g4 34. Rg6 g3 35. Nf3 gxh2 36. Nd4 e1=B 37. Nf5 Bf3 38. Rg5 Bfb7 39. Kd1 Bd2 40. Ke2 Bc1 41. Rg6 Ba6 42. Kf3 Kb1 43. Ke4 Kc2 44. Kd5 Kd1 45. Ke4 Ke2 46. Kd5 h1=B 47. Ke4 Kf1 48. Kd5 Kg1 49. Ke4 Kh2 50. Kd5 Bca3 51. Kd4 Bf4+ 52. Ke4 Qh4 53. Kd4 Qg4 54. g3 Qf3 55. Rf6 Qg2 56. Rg6 Qg1 57. Rg7 Bab7 58. Rg6 Bbg2 59. Rg5 Bae7 60. Rg6 Bb1 61. Rg5 a3 62. Rg6 a2 63. Rg5 a1=B 64. Rg6 hxg6 65. Nh4 Rh5 66. Nf5 Rg5 67. Nh4 Ra5 68. Nf5 Ra2 69. Nh4 Re2 70. Nf5 Re1 71. Nh4 Rf1 72. Nf5 Be6 73. Nh4 Bg4 74. Nf5 Be2 75. Nh4 Bb2 76. Nf5 Bc1 77. Nh4 Bd2 78. Nf5 Be1 79. Nh4 Nf6 80. Nf5 Nfd7 81. Nh4 Nc5 82. Nf5 Na4 83. Nh4 Nb2 84. Nf5 Nd1 85. Nh4 Bfd6 86. Nf5 Ba3 87. Nh4 Bc1 88. Nf5 Bcd2 89. Nh4 Bc2 90. Nf5 a5 91. Nh4 Ra6 92. Nf5 Rb6 93. Nh4 Rb4+ 94. Ke5 Ra4 95. Nf5 Ra1 96. Nh4 Rb1 97. Nf5 Ba3 98. Nh4 Bac1 99. Nf5 Nc6+ 100. Ke6 Ne5 101. Nh4 Nc4 102. Nf5 Ncb2 103. Nh4 a4 104. Nf5 a3 105. Nh4 a2 106. Nf5 a1=B 107. Nh4 Bh6 108. Kd6 Bg5 109. Kc5 Bh6 110. Kb4 Bg5 111. Ka3 Bd8 112. Nf5 gxf5 113. Kb4 f4 114. Ka3 f3 115. Kb4 Ba5+ 116. Ka3 Bb4+ 117. Ka2 Ba3

Answer (score 2):

> To start with White had 9 pieces to offer, and black has 9 bishops (5 black and 4 white) and a pawn in f3 in the end with the starting knight pair, rook pair, and a queen.
>
>  This means black pawn in A, B column was promoted in A1 while killing 1 white piece, and the black pawn in G, H column was promoted in H1 while killing 1 white piece (before white move h3). This means we got 4 leftover pawns in C, D, E, F columns while black has promoted 4 bishops (6 bishops in-game, 3 white, 3 black) and white had 7 pieces left to offer.
>
>  ***3 more bishops to promote while the black need to move to A1 or H1 with 7 pieces remaining?***
>
>
>  To go from C to A column white needs to sacrifice 2 pieces. The same story goes for F to H. This means black has 8 bishops (4 black,4 white) currently. While white only had 3 pieces left to offer. Meanwhile, the end positions show that black got 5 black bishops and a pawn at f3 in the end.
>
>   The leftover pawn was D, E of black. This means E pawn needs to be promoted in E1 for it to be black, this cost white 2 pieces for a black pawn to go to F row and back to E row. Finally, D pawn needs to go to the F column and this requires white to fork out another 2 pieces. Which white missing out a piece.

Which means:

> **Guilty**

Answer (score 2):

After a deliberation of several months, the jury has reached a verdict, and found the defendant

> **guilty.**

Since there are very few legal options for white's latest moves, we can deduce that two moves ago the board must have looked exactly like this:

> [image],

It is now white's turn, and the current position was reached by these moves:

```
1: c3 Bc2
2: b3 Nb2
```

(Anything else would require that the game was in an illegal position earlier, (**missed possibility edited in after OP's comment:**) or that the white piece that made the previous move was just captured, which would also add a ninth captured white piece to the tally.)

This means that all the bishops must have been promoted while b2 and c2 were unmoved.

Since all black pieces are accounted for, and all the 7 missing black pawns were promoted to bishops, the unmoved b2 pawn means that there can only have been one promotion on a1.

Taking this into account, let's count the minimum number of captures required to promote the black pawns:

- the black f-pawn is still on board
- the black a- and b-pawns needed **two** captures altogether (one capture for the b-pawn to move to the a file, and another capture for one of the pawns to promote on b1)
- the black c-pawn needed only **one** capture
- because both c2 and f2 were unmoved at the time, the black d and e-pawns needed to capture **three** pieces in total: either white's e-pawn moved before the white d-pawn, or vice versa. In either case, the corresponding black pawn needed to capture twice.
- Similarly, because of the unmoved f2, promoting the black g and h pawns required **three** captures.

Adding these up, we don't even need to check the colours of the bishops' squares to reach the verdict: black's promotions can only have happened if at least 9 white pieces were captured, but only 8 white pieces are missing.